# [robot_localization] Failed to meet update rate!

Tags: imu, navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a robot to localize, but getting a 'Failed to meet update rate!' error. Running Noetic on kernel 5.4.0-1047-raspi.

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

---

Error message in terminal:

```
[ WARN] [1641061436.663625132]: Failed to meet update rate! Took 0.31075859500000002633
```

Error message in log file:

```
1641055730.821605004 WARN /ekf_odom_node [/tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-robot-localization-2.7.3/src/ros_filter.cpp:1867(RosFilter<T>::periodicUpdate)] [topics: /rosout, /diagnostics, /tf, /odom/ekf/enc_imu] Failed to meet update rate! Took 0.23348387100000000949
```

Main launch file:

```
<launch>

    <node pkg="sensors" name="dummyOdom" type="dummyOdom.py" output="screen"/>

    <include file="$(find sensor_imu)/launch/sensor_imu.launch" />
    <include file="$(find ydlidar_ros_driver)/launch/scan.launch" />
    <include file="$(find navstack_pub)/launch/odom_ekf.launch" />
    <!-- <include file="$(find navstack_pub)/launch/amcl.launch" /> -->
    <include file="$(find husky_navigation)/launch/amcl.launch" />
    <include file="$(find husky_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch" />

    <arg name="map_file" value="$(find navstack_pub)/maps/map.yaml" />
    <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />


    <!-- Transformation Configuration ... Setting Up the Relationships Between Coordinate Frames -->
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser"              args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser_frame 30" />
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="imu_broadcaster"                 args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link imu 30" />
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="imu_broadcaster2"                args="0 0 0 0 0 0 imu imu_module_frame 30" />
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_broadcaster"   args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_footprint base_link 30" />
    <!-- odom to base_footprint transform will be provided by the robot_pose_ekf node -->
    <!-- map to odom will be provided by the AMCL -->
    <!-- <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom"                        args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 30" /> -->

    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_map"                    args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /world /map 30"/>
    <!-- <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_base_link"          args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /odom /base_footprint 30"/> -->

    <!-- <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_foorprint_to_link"     args="0.2245 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_footprint /base_link 40" /> -->


    <node pkg="rviz" name="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find navstack_pub)/launch/lidar.rviz" />
</launch>
```

odom_ekf.launch:

```
<!-- Odom node (Encoders + IMU) -->
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_odom_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="frequency" value="30"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odom/ekf/enc_imu"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
    <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

    <param name="odom0" value="/odom_dummy"/>
    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false" />
    <param name="odom0_relative" value="false" />
    <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10" />
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[
        <!-- false, false, false,
        false, false, false,
        true,  true,  false,
        false, false, true,
        false, false, false] -->

        false, false, false,
        false, false, false,
        false, false, false,
        false, false, false,
        false, false, false]
    </rosparam>

    <param name="imu0" value="/imu"/>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="false" />
    <param name="imu0_relative" value="true" />
    <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="10" />
    <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true" />
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[
        false, false, false,
        false, false, true,
        false, false, false,
        false, false, true,
        true,  false, false]
    </rosparam>
    <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true" />
    <param name="debug" value="true" />
    <param name="debug_out_file" value="debug_odom_ekf.txt" />
    <rosparam param="process_noise_covariance">[
        0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025,0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025,0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.005]
    </rosparam>
    <rosparam param="initial_estimate_covariance">[
        1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,
        0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9]
    </rosparam>
</node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393613/%5Brobot_localization%5D-failed-to-meet-update-rate!/) by [CounterOfKills](https://answers.ros.org/users/91875/counterofkills/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I had to guess, your issue is almost certainly this:

```
<param name="debug" value="true" />
```

Turning on debug mode spits a *ton* of text data out to disk, with matrices everywhere. Is there a reason you have it enabled?

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2022-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1